# WebSphere Shared Connections in Multiple Threads

Tags: multithreading, websphere, database-connection, shared, simultaneous

When a data source is configured for Shared Connections, will WebSphere give out Connections to the same physical database connection handle to two different threads simultaneously? In other words, does it really "share" physical database connections, or just "reuse" them?

IBM's documentation implies that it will give the same physical connection (in different Java Connection objects) to multiple thread. But, it doesn't say this explicitly, so one is left wondering how it really works.

Answer (score 0):

In certain conditions, it shares physical connections as specified here [Unshareable and shareable connections](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cdat_conshrnon.html?lang=en). However you cannot relay on it as it says:

> The user also cannot code an application that assumes sharing to take
>   place because it is up to the run time to decide whether or not to
>   share a particular connection.